# Weighted Overlay Missing Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, weighted-overlay

I am trying to create a bikeability index for some local roads. I have four inputs: traffic volume, speed limit, shoulder width, and slope. Each raster input has been re-classed to 6 classes. When I run a Weighted Overlay, my raster output contains [image: broken lines] that make the analysis useless. I assume this is because my volume, speed limit, and shoulder width do not have the same spatial extent as the slope (rasterized polylines vs continuous raster), and when I run the overlay with just the first three inputs I get a useful output. I can I solve this and utilize the continuous slope later in my analysis?

I am using arcmap 10.3.1